# Verify with WKT point is in a polygon SQL

Tags: sql-server, well-known-text

I'm using SQL Server and WKT to deal with geographic data. What I'd like to do is have something like :

`SELECT pt 
FROM point_table, polygon_table
where pt.point_table WITHIN ply.polygon_table`

Here pt is WKT point. Ex : `'POINT(lon lat)'`

and ply is WKT polygon Ex : `'POLYGON (( lon1 lat1 , lon2 lat2 , lon3 lat3 , lon4 lat4 ))'`

Comment: You have the order backwards in all your vertices.  If you ***think*** "lon,lat", you'll be sure to code it correctly.

Comment: The format for Well-Known Text is well documented.  It does *not* have the extra parenthesis around vertices, and POLYGON always starts/ends with a double-paren.  The Microsoft WITHIN operator is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933991.aspx). You have three unrelated tags.  Please edit the question.

Comment: @Vince Post edited. Thank you mate.  Microsoft `WITHIN` for geographic object is hat I was looking for. You could add this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation of the spatial types and functions standard is a bit quirky --

- The ST functions don't have an underscore between the ST and the function name (e.g. `STWithin` vice `ST_Within`)
- Rather than taking two operands, the operators are a function of the Geometry/Geography datatype (e.g., `pnt.geom.STWithin(ply.geom)` vice `ST_Within(pnt.geom,ply.geom)`)
- The function names are case sensitive (`STWithin` works, `stwithin` doesn't)

Assuming you have the data in Geometry format in columns with name "geom" and id columns "idcol", then the point within polygon join could look like:

```
SELECT ply.idcol plyid, pnt.idcol pntid
FROM polygon_table ply
INNER JOIN point_table pnt
    ON pnt.geom.STWithin(ply.geom) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of intersecting a geometry point with a WKT polygon:

```
declare @tempPoly geometry;

set @tempPoly = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((3168400.501482 1706746.617880,3131160.918149 1690210.159546,3164754.668149 1673022.659546,3174650.501482 1688517.451213,3173869.251482 1700366.409546,3168400.501482 1706746.617880))', 2877);

select * from pointstable as pt

--this is where you link the temporary geometry to your spatial table

 where pt.shape.STIntersects(@tempPoly) = 1
```

So basically the opposite would have a where clause similar to:

```
 where @tempPoint.STIntersects(polygonTable.shape) = 1
```